# Why does C++ not provide a First-In-First-Out singly-linked list?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, standards, c++20

In the C++ standard library, `list` is doubly-linked list; `forward_list` is singly-linked list but supports Last-In-First-Out only.

However, the First-In-First-Out singly-linked list has been widely used for its low space-overhead than other list-like containers (except `forward_list`). So I wonder:

**Why does C++ not provide a First-In-First-Out singly-linked list?**

Comment: how about `std::deque`?

Comment: `std::deque` is not a singly-linked list.

Comment: or rather `std::queue` is exactly that: FIFO

Comment: Depending on use-case, perhaps a [`std::queue`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue)?

Comment: Probably because committees couldn't find common use cases for such a data structure (just like me at the moment)

Comment: `std::queue` is implemented as `std::deque` by default, which is not singly-linked list.

Comment: not really, you can choose the containertype for a queue, eg `std::queue<T,std::list<T>>`, `queue` is just an adaptor

Comment: All containers mentioned above have more space-overhead than a pure singly-linked list.

Comment: @xmllmx How would you implement a FIFO singly linked list? Are you sure that it is even possible?

Comment: @eerorika  Add at tail pointer, remove at head.  This is common.

Comment: @eerorika, just use a head pointer and a tail pointer, that's all.

Comment: How about std::forward_list?

Comment: If you're worried about space overhead, it can't go without saying that a linked list has unnecessary overhead for every single element compared to something like a deque. Without a more involved allocator, every single element is a separate free store allocation that includes metadata about at least its size. Within the list itself, every single element is accompanied by a pointer.

Comment: Such a list would need to traverse the whole list in order to pop ?

Comment: Do you really need a singly linked list?  It is basically the worst data structure you can use from a performance sense.  A deque should be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: @stark, `std::forward_list` only supports Last-In-First-Out, I want it to be First-In-First-Out.

Comment: @chris, `std::deque` cannot customize its underlying chunk size that is implementation-defined, but I want to customize the underlying chunk size, so `std::deqee` is not chosen.

Comment: @xmllmx: You can't customize the underlying chunk size of a `list` either.

Comment: @NicolBolas, I can use `std::vector` as the FIFO singly-linked list's element type. So, I can customize the chunk size.

Comment: @M.M Yes, we need.

Comment: @xmllmx: "*I can use std::vector as the FIFO singly-linked list's element type.*" I don't understand what you mean by that. Are you saying that you would have a hypothetical `list<vector<T>>`? How does that in any way affect "chunk size" of the `list` allocations? Or more specifically what do you mean by "chunk size", and how would a `deque<vector<T>>` be unable to get the same benefit?

Comment: @NicolBolas, "chunk size" is the `std::vector`'s size. Consider `std::deque`, which is a list but its elements are of `std::vector`. Also, `deque<vector<T>>` cannot control how many `vector<T>` in a chunk, which is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily create one yourself by augmenting `forward_list` with a before-the-end iterator to implement `back()` and `push_back()`:

```
template<class T>
struct fifo_list {
    std::forward_list<T> base;
    std::forward_list<T>::iterator before_end = base.before_begin();
    fifo_list(fifo_list const& other) { for (auto t : other.base) push_back(t); }
    fifo_list(fifo_list&&) = default;
    auto front() { return base.front(); }
    void pop_front() { base.pop_front(); }
    auto back() { return *before_end; }
    void push_back(T t) { before_end = base.insert_after(before_end, t); }
};
```

This can then be used with the `std::queue` adapter.

The overhead associated with maintaining the `before_end` iterator is presumably the reason why this facility (`back` and `push_back`) is not included in `forward_list` already.